# Close modal with iframe after success

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap modal with an iframe inside. 
That iframe has a contact form in it with an uploader. I want to close the modal when the form is submitted.

How do you do that?

I tried to use

```
success:function(){
    $('#modal .close', parent.document).trigger('click');
}
```

But that obviously is blocked for cross domain access.

The modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{ 'Vraag uw beregeningsplan aan' | t }}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe></iframe>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
          $(this).find('iframe').attr('src','//link-to-form/')
        });

      });
    </script>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: if the contact form is yours, why don't you abandon `iframe` and use an `ajax get` to populate `modal-body` with the html of the form.  Then wire up that submit button to close the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Well Not sure from the description if the Form inside the iframe is your own form or some external web form.

In case its your own form then write this jquery code in the inside form

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function () {                    

                window.parent.$('#modal').modal('hide');

            });

        });
```

where myForm is the ID for the inside form